# Algebraic proof for simple set theory problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that:

$(A^{c}\cap B^{c} \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (A \cap C) = C$

(cmp = complement)

Now, one way to solve this is to take a small universe $U$, say $U$ = *{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}*, draw the Venn diagram, figure out the union-ed parts of the equation and prove it.

How can we do this purely algebraically? using the laws of sets like the idempotent law, duality, domination, absorption etc?

Comment: "The members of C are in A, in B or in neither of these."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algebraic way to solve this is to remember that union and intersection are distributive over one another, therefore:

$$\begin{align}
& (A^c\cap B^c\cap C) \cup (B\cap C) \cup (A\cap C) &=&(\text{un-distribute } \cap C) \\
& \Big( (A^c\cap B^c) \cup B \cup A\Big)\cap C &=&(\text{distribute }\cup B) \\
& \Big( (A\cup B)^c \cup (B\cup A)\Big)\cap C &=&(\text{de Morgan's law}) \\
& &=&C
\end{align}$$

(As Theo suggested, using de Morgan's law shortens the proof.)

Comment: Thanks both of you for the insights. I've to brush up with the rules though. Doing this after a long, long time.

Comment: This is a nice way of inserting reasons in a sequence of aligned equalities.